# I want to show an empty cell in a table when there is no data for that cell

Tags: php, mysql

Our organisation offers morning & afternoon ski tours at several different levels. Not all tour levels occur every session and sometimes there may be more than one tour at a given level at the same time.  I want to display guest numbers by date, type of tour and time of day. I have no problem retrieving the numbers, my problem is the display.  Where there is no data I can't figure out how to make it show a blank cell, or one with a 0 in it.

The image shows a sample of what I'm getting, which I modified a bit to show what I want.

[image: sample output table]
Hopefully this will clarify my issue. On Mar 28 there were guests for all 5 types of tours in the morning and afternoon.  On Mar 29 no one took the BlGrn Tour so its amID value of 2 does not exist in the database for that date (see below), nor does the pmID value of 1 for the Grn tour appear for that afternoon and all the cells with data get shifted to the left.

```
memberID    amID    pmID    date    guestsAM    guestsPM    statsID
   191        5      5  28/03/2016     2           1    17322
   192        4      3  28/03/2016     4           4    17323
   52         0      1  28/03/2016     0           2    17324
   408        5      4  28/03/2016     2           7    17325
   370        0      2  28/03/2016     0           2    17326
   624        3      3  28/03/2016     3           5    17327
   480        1      2  28/03/2016     3           5    17329
   571        4      0  28/03/2016     3           0    17330
   427        3      0  28/03/2016     2           0    17331
   528        2      0  28/03/2016     3           0    17332

   13         4      2  29/03/2016     3           4    17333
   179        5      0  29/03/2016     3           0    17334
   147        1      0  29/03/2016     3           0    17335
   571        0      4  29/03/2016     0           2    17336
   426        0      3  29/03/2016     0           2    17338
   100        0      3  29/03/2016     0           3    17339
   165        3      0  29/03/2016     5           0    17340
   480        5      0  29/03/2016     1           0    17341
   427        1      5  29/03/2016     2           4    17342
   613        3      0  29/03/2016     4           0    17343
```

This is the code which retrieves the morning data. If there is more than one tour of a given type at the same time this code successfully adds up the guest numbers for those tours.

```
$sql = "SELECT *, SUM(guestsAM) as guestsam FROM stats GROUP BY date, amID";
$mar_am_tour = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
```

This is one variant of the code that I have tried to display the data for one tour type.  If amID occurs for that date it works like a charm. If not it simply moves what should be in the next cell into the empty space. (see the image)

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mar_am_tour)) {
    if ($row[date] == '2016-03-29') { 
        if ($row[amID] == 1) {
            echo '<td class="members">' . $row[guestsam] .  '</td>'; 
        } else  {
            if ($row[amID] == '') {
                echo '<td class="members"></td>';
            }
        }
    }
```

I've also tried replacing Srow[amID] with $row[guestsam] == 0 and $row[guestsam] == ''  in the 'else' statement and reversing the order of the if statements. Replacing the if statement after the "else" with

```
echo '<td class="members"></td>';
```

results in an empty cell between each cell with data.

I think what I need is something along the lines of

if ($row[amID] ***== 1 does not exist for this date*** ) { echo '';

I found this

```
function is_blank($value) {
return empty($value) && !is_numeric($value);
```

}

on "How to implement is_empty" but I have no idea if it's what I need nor how to use it.

Comment: did you check what the exact value of `$row[amID]` is when the cell needs to be empty? Did you try `is_empty($row[amID])`? Do you need to check for empty? In other words do you need the additional `if` in the `else` part?

Comment: Could you clarify how to use is_empty? If I try to put it into my if statement I get an error message.  I've updated my original question with more information which may clarify things.

Comment: There is an error in your logic. Your `amID` is never empty, it is 0, or 1 or 2 and so on. So you should check for 0 not for ''. Same goes for `pmID`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you have 5 categories like "Grn", "BlGrn", etc. then you have IDs for them in your DB, are these IDs from 1 to 5? if so, why don't you just add an `order by amID` to your query and then in your loop keep track of last `amID` and see if it's not the one you're expecting, then you have skipped one. it means you did not have that `amID` in your results. so you can put an empty cell instead. have you tried this logic?

Comment: I'm clearly out of my depth here. EhsanT could you provide a sample of the code that you would use? What does work, and what I am trying to avoid, is adding dummy data to insert the missing amID categories.  That is: insert a fictitious member assigned to a tour that did not occur and therefore had 0 guests.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by RST, check for value that $row[amID] has when the cell needs to be empty. Also, your code has trivial mistake

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mar_am_tour)) {
if ($row['date'] == '2016-03-29') { 
    if ($row['amID'] == 1) {
        echo '<td class="members">' . $row['guestsam'] .  '</td>'; 
    } else  {
        if (!empty($row['amID'])) {
            echo '<td class="members"></td>';
        }
       /*what if $row['amID'] != '' . 
        *Either put an else block here or remove the if block and just 
        *echo '<td class="members"></td>'
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: Just echoing the <td></td> after the else puts an empty cell between every cell that I want. I've updated my question which may clarify my issue which basically is how to deal with the absence of the value of 1, or any of the other possible values, for amID on a given date in a given time period.